# How to calculate $\frac{\partial \mathbf{A}}{\partial \mathbf{x}}$?

Tags: matrix-calculus

How to calculate $\frac{\partial \mathbf{A}}{\partial \mathbf{x}}$?

Here $\mathbf{A}$ is a matrix and $\mathbf{x}$ is a vector. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the Jacobian of a vector valued function. Unfortunately this popular notation is not very self explanatory.

[**See Jacobian**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant)

Comment: OK, I understand. Thank you for your answer.